# Is it correct to say you are really aside to be old?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, phrases

I was watching a short film and one of the characters said: *"You really are aside to be old, sweetheart"*, and I wonder when it's right to say that, and the meaning of it. Here's the video:

*[Horror Short Film “Special Day”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkO6ppcvFro&t=33)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say that you misheard the phrase. It makes more sense if he were saying: "You really are a sight to behold, sweetheart" - meaning that she's looking very special today.

But I might be mistaken as well. ;) *shrug*

Comment: I couldn't find it in the video, but that was my thought exactly.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty it's just a couple of seconds after the time `t=33` posted ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, I heard it now. stez nailed it.

Comment: You're not mistaken, stez. That's what the gentleman said to the birthday girl.

Comment: thank you stez for your response I really appreciate it!.